# How to make accordian class expanded by default

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know if anyone knows how to make an accordion expand the first item only?  Here's an example, but I'd like the first one expanded, or depending on the circumstances, maybe the second or third, or all.

Example that shows all collapsed: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion

Need to determine how to make one or more expand.  Thanks!

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Accordion</h2>

  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So do you want the first item to be expanded when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [first-child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) for this. Just wrap all the accordions in a container and then wrap the button and content for each accordion in a container as well:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* EXPAND THE FIRST ACCORDION */
.acc-item:first-child .panel {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="acc-item">
    <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="acc-item">
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="acc-item">
    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

define a class `selected` to `display:block` and toggle that class instead of changing the display style on the actual element. Then just add `active` to the first element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.panel.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach, based on my own preferred style of page construction...

1. I want my markup — that is, my DOM structure, to be semantic; to logically model the thing I'm implementing.
2. I like to avoid directly manipulating styles on elements. I manipulate the *state* of the element, then apply styles to the different states. This generally means adding descriptive classes based on what a thing *is* and its *state*, not classes based on *appearance.*

From those "rules" I decided that an accordion is a *widget* -- a control that contains several sections. Each section has a *heading* and a *panel* (I stayed with using `button` for the heading, like you, but I'd probably make it a `<header>` myself)

```
<!-- an accordion -->
<div class="accordion">
    <section class="panel">...</section>
    <section class="panel">...</section>
    <section class="panel">...</section>
</div>

<!-- a section within an accordion -->
<section class="panel">
    <button>Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      ... contents of panel ...
    </div>
</section>
```

I started with your styles and modified the selectors to match my new layout, starting each selector with `.accordion` so it only affects things within an accordion widget.
`.accordion { ... }` which you marked your *button* with became `.accordion > section > button` to select the button within each of the sections in the accordion control.

Then, since I don't like directly manipulating styles on elements, I decided each section could be `open` or "not-open" -- that is, the class "open" will be *present* or *absent* on a section. Doing this allows me to simply *declare* that a section is **open** in the markup:

```
<section class="open> ... </section> <!-- a section that starts open -->
<setion> ... </section>              <!-- a section that is not-open (aka closed) -->
```

This also simplifies the javascript; all it has to do is toggle the "open" class — it doesn't have to test the current state.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion > section > button')
    .forEach(function(el) {
        console.log('id:: ' + el.className);
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            this.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');    // <---
        });
    });
```

I worked on this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/5oaq1ve8/) but here it is as a stack snippet

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion > section > button')
    .forEach(function(el) {
        console.log('id:: ' + el.className);
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            this.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
        });
    });
```

```css
.accordion > section > button {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion > section.open > button,
.accordion > section > button:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.accordion > section > .panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: none;
}
.accordion > section.open > .panel {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<!-- I added classes to the buttons just to see them being found in the browser console. They're not necessary -->

<div class="accordion">
    <section class="open"> <!-- _declared_ as already open -->
        <button id="one">Section 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
            do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <button id="two">Section 2</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <button id="three">Section 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

In real life I would put the css and the js in their own separate files. My page would include these in appropriate places.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="accordion.css">
<script src="accordion.js"></script>
```